# How to design ExtJS Container using CSS?

Tags: css, extjs5, cls

I have used the `ExtJS` properties of `cls`, `bodyCls`, `componentCls` but not getting the result.

**For an example:**

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: document.body,
    title: 'User Form',
    height: 350,
    width: 300,
    cls: 'form',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        name: 'firstName'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
        name: 'lastName'
    }, {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Date of Birth',
        name: 'birthDate'
    }]
});
```

**Now CSS:**

```
.form {
    background-color:orange !important;
}
```

I wanted to get background color orange but I am not getting the result what I want.

**ANY HELP WOULD BE GREAT APPRECIATED**

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply class like below (need to apply background to the body of form):

```
.form .x-panel-body-default {
    background-color:orange !important;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2k5r)**

Hope this will help/guide you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @rohit. But one thing How do you get or identified the .x-panel-body-default. I mean How shall you get the default ExtJS default CSS classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add css like this to Panel config,

Like `bodyStyle: 'background: orange !important',` in your panel

`Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {`
`renderTo: document.body,`
`title: 'User Form',`
`height: 350,`
`width: 300,`
`cls: 'form',`
`bodyStyle: 'background: orange !important',`
`bodyPadding: 10,`
`defaultType: 'textfield',`